# NullPointerException в адаптере

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть список, в нем кнопка удаления. Работает нормально - до тех пор, пока не останется один элемент списка, в этом случае приложение крашит с `indexBoundOfException`

Попытался зафиксить проблему, добавив + 1, но особо не помогло)Честно говоря не понимаю, откуда это может быть.

Голова уже кипит, до таких банальных ошибок.

Код адаптера:

```
  public void addItem(Note note) {
        itemList.add(note);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        itemList.remove(position + 1);
        notifyItemRemoved(position + 1);
    }


 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("onBindHolder", "Сработал");

        Note item = getItemList().get(position);
        Log.d("position", "position " + position);

        holder.getDelete().setOnClickListener(new DeleteItemPosition(this, position));
```

Класс листенера:

```
public class DeleteItemPosition implements View.OnClickListener {
   private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
   private int position;

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public DeleteItemPosition(RecyclerViewAdapter adapter, int position) {
        setAdapter(adapter);
        setPosition(position);
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

    private void setAdapter(RecyclerViewAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    private void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        adapter.deleteItem(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему Вы удаляете элемент с номером `position + 1`? Зачем единицу прибавляете?

Comment: @post_zeew это просто попытка избавиться от ошибки, я предположил, что он удаляет позицию - 1. До этого + 1 не присутствовало.

Comment: Покажите весь адаптер.

Comment: @post_zeew я поставил - 1, вылетела ошибка.
Убрал плюсы и минус 1 - запустил, заработало нормально.

Ват.

Comment: @post_zeew оно работает о0

Comment: Ну, при нормальной логике адаптера, если необходимо удалять элемент, в котором нажата кнопка удаления, то и удалять нужно элемент в позиции `position`, не больше, не меньше.

Comment: @post_zeew ну да, так и получилось

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените:

```
itemList.remove(position + 1);
notifyItemRemoved(position + 1);
```

на:

```
itemList.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

При нормальной логике адаптера, если необходимо удалить элемент, в котором нажата кнопка удаления, то и удалять нужно элемент в позиции `position`, не больше, не меньше.